# telnet client response how to decode it

Tags: decode, telnet, cisco

**telnet client response how to decode it**

I think it is a specific response as all cisco servers have the same response
. What is the name of this text and how do I decrypt it

> '\xff\xfb\x01\xff\xfb\x03\xff\xfd\x18\xff\xfd\x1f'

```
import socket
import sys

HOST = 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx'   # this is my cisco server ip 
PORT = 23
import socket
import gzip
s = socket.socket()
#Connecting using telnet
s.connect((HOST,23))
a = s.recv(10000)
print(str(a))
#'\xff\xfb\x01\xff\xfb\x03\xff\xfd\x18\xff\xfd\x1f'
```

Comment: The `\xff\xfb\x01\xff\xfb\x03\xff\xfd\x18\xff\xfd\x1f` sequence looks like (part of) telnet negotiation from the server to the client or vice versa…

Comment: yes it is . how i can decode it

Comment: @pradosh-nair if u can help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[RFC-854](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc854) explains the protocol frames, each frame contains options that are maintained on this [IANA page](https://www.iana.org/assignments/telnet-options/telnet-options.xhtml).

The byte stream "\xff\xfb\x01\xff\xfb\x03\xff\xfd\x18\xff\xfd\x1f" is made of 4 commands:

First command:

- ff: Start a command
- fb: Indicates the desire to begin performing
- 01: ECHO mode

Second command:

- ff: Start of a command
- fb: Indicates the desire to begin performing
- 03: GO-AHEAD mode: TCP is a full duplex transport protocol, so the Cisco router asks not to use the GO-AHEAD character that is only useful on half duplex links

Third command:

- ff: Start of a command
- fd: Indicates the request that the other party perform
- 18: terminal type

Last command:

- ff: Start of a command
- fd: Indicates the request that the other party perform
- 1f: Negotiate About Window Size

Therefore, your Cisco server said:

- I will echo the characters I receive from you
- Do not use the half duplex mode, we do not need this
- Send me your terminal type
- Start negotiating the window size with me

You must read [RFC-854](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc854) and [IANA page](https://www.iana.org/assignments/telnet-options/telnet-options.xhtml) to parse the response.